# If I use an element chasing proof, can I prove the identity of two sets false by proving the negation of that identity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For example, if A=(B∖C) is true, the following are true:

1. ∀x(x∈A→x∈B∧~x∈C)
2. ∀x(x∈B∧~x∈C→x∈A)

(A=(B∖C) is just an arbitrary example; I don't really know its truth value)

But this sounds really just like a biconditional to me, if we take

∀x(x∈A) as P

∀x(x∈B∧~x∈C) as Q

then the truth of A=(B∖C) just means P↔Q. So surely if I want to prove A=(B∖C) is false, I can treat it as ~(P↔Q), which is the same as (P→~Q)∨(Q→~P).

Could anyone confirm if I am right please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 
$$\forall x\,(x\in A\to (x\in B\land \neg x\in C)) $$
is not the same as $P\to Q$, which is 
$$\forall x(x\in A)\;\to \;\forall x(x\in B\land \neg x\in C) .$$
Actually, your $P$ and $Q$ are trivially wrong for arbitrary sets $A,B,C$ because there is no set that contains everything.
Instead, in order to prove $A\ne B\setminus C$ you could show that at laeast one of the properties 1., 2. is wrong, so you show that
$$ \exists x(x\in A\land\neg( x\in B\land x\notin C))\;\lor\;\exists x( x\in B\land x\notin C\land x\notin A)$$

Comment: Thank you! So to clarify, I can indeed prove the identity of two sets false by proving the negation of that identity. What I did wrong was that I misunderstood the negation of the identity: since A=(B∖C) is the same as ∀x(x∈A↔(x∈B∧¬x∈C)), its negation is ∃x¬(x∈A↔(x∈B∧¬x∈C)), which is also equivalent to the last line of your answer. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

As *Hagen* said,$\def\less{\smallsetminus}$$\def\eq{\Leftrightarrow}$$\def\imp{\Rightarrow}$ your definition of $P,Q$ means that "$A = B \less C$" is not equivalent to "$P \eq Q$". Furthermore, as *Crostul* pointed out, "$\neg ( P \eq Q )$" is not equivalent to "$( P \imp \neg Q ) \lor ( Q \imp \neg P )$", and a counter-example would be when $P,Q$ are both false.

However, "$\forall x\ ( x \in A \imp x \in B \land x \notin C ) \land \forall x\ ( x \in B \land x \notin C \imp x \in A )$" is equivalent to "$\forall x\ ( x \in A \eq x \in B \land x \notin C )$", and its negation would be "$\neg \forall x\ ( x \in A \eq x \in B \land x \notin C )$" or equivalently "$\exists x\ ( \neg ( x \in A \eq x \in B \land x \notin C ) )$".

To really understand what is going on, you have to understand the meaning of the implication as well as the quantifiers and how to evaluate the truth value of a quantified statement. Otherwise everything will just be like a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is not $(P→ \sim Q)∨(Q→ \sim P)$. You have
$$\sim (P \leftrightarrow Q) = \ \sim ((P \rightarrow Q)\wedge (Q \rightarrow P)) = (\sim (P \rightarrow Q)) ∨ (\sim (Q \rightarrow P))  =$$
$$= (P \wedge (\sim Q)) ∨ ((\sim P) \wedge Q )$$